# Removing Objects from Legend on Webmap

Tags: legend, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to remove a couple elements from my webmap legend (the rest service title and the world map).

[image]

Here is what my legend code looks like:

```
var legend = new Legend({
     map: map,
     layer:D_ml.visibleLayers
}, "legendDiv");
legend.startup();
```

This is how I set up my `D_ml.visible` layers :

```
C_ml = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://imcltpdarcp01.duke-energy.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/TEST_DEC_DEI/MapServer");//,{opacity: 0.6};

D_ml = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://imcltpdarcp01.duke-energy.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/TEST_DEC_DEI/MapServer",{opacity: 0.75});

map.addLayers([C_ml,D_ml]);

C_ml.setVisibleLayers([2,3]);
D_ml.setVisibleLayers([0,1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can made this either  :

1. Using JS by seting the layer title to blank string , and this after add all layers to map  :

   ```
   map.on("layers-add-result", function (evt) {
     // custom layer info  
     var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function (layer, index) {
        return {layer:layer.layer, title:" "};
     });

     if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
        var legend= new Legend({
           map: map,
           layer:D_ml.visibleLayers,
           layerInfos: layerInfo
       }, "legendDiv");
       legend.startup();
     }
   });
   ```

Ps:You need to import `dojo/_base/array` (named here `arrayUtils` in callback function)

2. Or simply Using Css Styling by setting the class to `display:none` :

   ```
   .esriLegendServiceLabel {
       display:none;
   }
   ```

Comment: The second option worked to remove the titles, thank you. However is there a way to remove the basemap entirely from the legend? It is separate from my D_ml.visiblelayers layer.

Comment: @EthanHeidtman note that the first methode removes the Basemap from legend , just import required class (array , does it throws error ? )

Comment: layerInfos define all layer used to render Legend , so Basemap wont be rendred , if you have any issue please tell me

Comment: The first method did work! I needed to delete my cookies and whatnot. thank you so much!! @bRIMOsBor

Comment: I'm so glad it helps you :)